# React component modal is open at load and never closes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm experimenting a modal that opens when I click on a button, but it's open at the beginning and it never closes.

How to make sure it is closed at mount and that is closes when I click outside the message box ?

I'm adapting the [modal demo](https://mui.com/components/modal/) from material core:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';

const style = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    width: 400,
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: 24,
    p: 4
};

export class Contact extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false,
            setOpen: false
        }
        this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    }
    static displayName = Contact.name;
    handleOpen() { this.setState({ setOpen: true }); }
    handleClose() { this.setState({ setOpen: false }); }
 
    render() {

        return(
            <div>
                <div className="center">
                    <Button onClick={() => this.handleOpen()}>Contact us</Button>
                </div>
                <Modal open={() => this.state.open()} onClose={()=> this.handleClose()}
                aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title" aria-describedby="modal-modal-description">
                    <Box sx={style}>
                      <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
                          Contact us
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                          Contact us at hello @ mycompany.com
                      </Typography>
                    </Box>
                </Modal>
            </div >
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using and updating two different state values `open` and `setOpen`. That's why it was opening and never closes. Updated your code in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-demp-40vzc?file=/demo.js:0-1528). Another issue was you were using `open={() => this.state.open()}` for modal state, which was always returning true. Instead you need to use the `open={this.state.open}`

here is the complete code.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Modal from "@mui/material/Modal";

const style = {
  position: "absolute",
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: "background.paper",
  border: "2px solid #000",
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4
};

class Contact extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
    this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }
  static displayName = Contact.name;
  handleOpen() {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  }
  handleClose() {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="center">
          <Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>Contact us</Button>
        </div>
        <Modal
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
          aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
        >
          <Box sx={style}>
            <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
              Contact us
            </Typography>
            <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
              Contact us at hello @ mycompany.com
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 1):

You got mistaken between working with classes and hooks. Since you are using classes and `setState`, you should set the state of the variable `open` that determines if the modal is open or not (it is a boolean value).

The property `open` of Material UI's Modal component expect a boolean value that determines if the modal should be in open state or not. You are assigning the state property `open` of yours into the `open` property, which is okay. But you need to update it with `setState` when needed.

So, instead of `this.setState({ setOpen: true });` and `this.setState({ setOpen: false });` You should use `this.setState({ open: true });` and `this.setState({ open: false });`.

The state property `setOpen` is unnecesary in this case.
This is the fixed code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';

const style = {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
    width: 400,
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: 24,
    p: 4
};

export class Contact extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false
        }
        this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this);
        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    }
    static displayName = Contact.name;
    handleOpen() { this.setState({ open: true }); }
    handleClose() { this.setState({ open: false }); }
 
    render() {

        return(
            <div>
                <div className="center">
                    <Button onClick={() => this.handleOpen()}>Contact us</Button>
                </div>
                <Modal open={this.state.open} onClose={()=> this.handleClose()}
                aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title" aria-describedby="modal-modal-description">
                    <Box sx={style}>
                      <Typography id="modal-modal-title" variant="h6" component="h2">
                          Contact us
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                          Contact us at hello @ mycompany.com
                      </Typography>
                    </Box>
                </Modal>
            </div >
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Also `<Modal open={() => this.state.open()}` should be `<Modal open={this.state.open}` doesn't it ?

Comment: Yes. You are right, I'll edit it